# asp.net MVC And I need to setup 301 redirects

Tags: redirect, iis, model-view-controller, http-status-code-301

I have a site moving from php to asp.net MVC And I need to setup 301 redirects for it so like www.mystoresitem.com/products/widget1name  needs to redirect to www.mystoresitem.com/widget1name for 700+ different widgets how do I redirect this with out doing it for each product/widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to be sure that you installed [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module in your IIS

Then in your web.config just add this rules inside `system.webServer` section:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirects to products">
            <match url="^products/(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It will automatically redirect all your urls

`www.mystoresitem.com/products/{productname}` to `www.mystoresitem.com/{productname}`

Comment: if I need to go one more folder  www.somestoresite.com/products/soy-candles/ {productname}  and redirect to www.mystoresitem.com/{productname}    I tried to just add to your rule above like this  <match url="^products/soy-candles/(.*)" />  But it is not working.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Which folder? Can you please provide example

Comment: www.somestoresite.com/products/soy-candles/ {productname}  and redirect to www.somestoresite.com/{productname}

Comment: Create another rule and add it before rule, what i mentioned in answer `<rule name="Redirects to products soy-candles" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^products/soy-candles/(.*)" /><action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" /></rule>`

Comment: with that it redirects to this  www.mystoresitem.com/soy-candles/ {productname}     I want it to go to this:  www.mystoresitem.com/{productname}

Comment: If you will place `rule name="Redirects to products soy-candles"` above `rule name="Redirects to products"`, it should work properly

Comment: If everything is working for you, can you please accept the answer